# Which filesystem should I use on my SD Card?

Tags: external-sd, sd-card, lineageos, exfat, fairphone-3

I have a 1 TB SD Card in a Fairphone 3 running the latest Lineage.
Recently I had issues with random reboots and now found out that my SD Card is formatted with FAT32, which might cause troubles on such a disk size.

I tested a bit, and unlike lots of info on the internet, both exFAT and ext4 seem to be recognised just fine. And there is also F2FS which is touted as a good choice.

So, which FS should I use? I use Linux everywhere so desktop OS compatibility is not a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best file system for an external SD card](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105241/best-file-system-for-an-external-sd-card)

Comment: unfortunately not, as it is quite dated